ArgoCD ignores every enabled besides 'global.enabled' in my values.yaml file for vault. How can I circumvent that bug?
I pulled hashicorp vault using helm. I copied the values.yaml file, changed global.enabled to false and enabled some parts like server, ui etc. Then I installed vault with helm using the edited values.yaml file. As expected, those parts I specificly enabled have been installed, while the rest didnt.
However, when I create an application in ArgoCD to manage my vault in Kubernetes and refer to my edited values.yaml file, it only recognizes global.enabled while ignoring every other enabled configuration. This leads to two options: Set global.enabled to false and have no parts to sync or set global.enabled to true and let ArgoCD check for every part of vault, even those where I set enabled to false. The latter also causes issues with RBAC policies, which leads to errors.
I use the helm-vault version 0.29.1. The argocd version is v2.12.1. The helm version installed in argocd is v3.15.2. The helm version I installed vault with is v3.16.3. I looked at github releases and didn't see any relevant differences between helm version 3.15 and 3.16 in the changelog.
It seems to me that this is a bug from ArgoCD or its in-built helm. How can I circumvent it?
